# etcd snapshot save vs copy file from member/snap/db?

Tags: nosql, copy, backup, snapshot, etcd

I'm using etcd v3.5.7 and documentation says that when you perform a backup of your cluster, then you either:

- `snapshot save file.db`
- `cp member/snap/db`

But I'm not quite sure that these operations are equivalent and I guess that `snapshot save file.db` also provides kinda sync operation to detect latest state of cluster and then copy that into `file.db`, whereas simple copying a file from `member/snap/db` doesn't provide that functionality and is just dump copy, however in a cluster could be some pending etc events that are not yet committed to the cluster `db`.

I don't get it, are they equivalent or not?